# Which could be the best method for backup, Azure backup or thru snapshot method?

Tags: backup, azure, snapshot

Anybody work with pricing on those two methods? If so, what is the pros and cons to define.

Which could be the best method for backup and restore in Azure;

is it Azure backup or thru snapshot method, especially When comes to pricing?

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the cost then snapshot is cheaper from an Azure consumption perspective.

Simple Example with 100 GB VM

Azure backup around 15$

Disk snapshot around 5$

**But** there is so much more management and time consuming dealing with snapshot so if you count the cost of your time(which you should) then Azure backup will be way cheaper.

Use [Azure Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/) to calculate Azure consumption. (Snapshot is located under Storage account)